# Argument Matcher does not validate argument

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-testing

I'm new to testing in Android, and have decided to start by working through Mockito examples from http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3

To fully understand what's going on, I've decided to branch out from the example, this is my code:

```
@Test
public void testMatchers() throws Exception
{
  LinkedList <String> mockedList = mock (LinkedList.class);
  when (mockedList.contains(argThat(isValidStr()))).thenReturn(true);
  System.out.println(mockedList.contains("Asdf")); // prints 'true', as expected
  System.out.println(mockedList.contains("asdf")); // prints 'true' which I guess makes sense... but shouldn't the argument matcher complain somehow?

}
public static ArgumentMatcher<String> isValidStr()
{
  return new ArgumentMatcher<String> ()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean matches ( Object argument ) 
    {
      String str = (String) argument;
      return (str.charAt(0) > 'A' || str.charAt(0) < 'Z' ) // if first letter is capitalized
    }
  }
}
```

All tests are passing, with 0 exceptions/errors.  Also, I put a breakpoint at the start of the 'matches' function and it never gets hit.

3 questions:
1) Why isn't my argument matcher complaining about a bad argument?
2) What is the expected output after detecting a bad argument?
3) How would the code look like to detect a bad argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know why your breakpoint isn't firing, but I tossed a `System.out.println("Hello")` breakpoint in the matcher and it gets hit just fine. As it turns out, both "asdf" and "Asdf" match in your test, because your condition in the matcher has a `||` instead of a `&&`. Once I corrected that, and switched to `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`:

   ```
   return (str.charAt(0) >= 'A' && str.charAt(0) <= 'Z' );
   ```

   ...then I get `true` and `false` respectively, as expected.

   Note that it's safer to mock interfaces like `List` and `Deque` rather than concrete classes like `LinkedList`, because concrete classes can have final methods that Mockito silently fails to mock. (In real world non-example tests you should probably use a real `LinkedList` and [test state instead of interaction](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/07/12/should-i-worry-about-the-unexpected/).)
2. Because you're using the matcher in a `when` statement, you're setting the expected behavior for when the matcher matches. When it doesn't match, if you haven't set any other expectations, Mockito returns its [default boolean return value](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2), `false`.
3. [Unlike EasyMock's record-replay pattern](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock), that actively catches bad interactions during the test, Mockito has a stub-test-verify pattern that only "checks" for bad interactions if you manually ask it to do so:

   ```
   // Verify that contains is never called with an invalid string.
   verify(mockedList, never()).contains(argThat(not(isValidStr()));
   ```

   By convention, this would be at the end of your test. Another obvious verification would look like this:

   ```
   verify(mockedList).contains(argThat(isValidStr()));
   ```

   ...but this would actually pass, because it would match your first call with "Asdf" and ignore your second call with "asdf". You could solve this by adding `verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedList)` to the verification above, but usually those default values like `false` and `null` will break your test assertions or system-under-test anyway.